# Jhipster microservice without registry does not show swagger

Tags: jhipster

I have created jhipster microservice app without any registry or gateway as I will be using aws managed gateway.
But I don't see the swagger ui.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior by choice of the JHipster team. So you have to implement it by yourself

Comment: Okay, done. That is what I have implemented.